# Cannot read properties of undefined in resolver in Apollo GraphQL

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-server

I'm trying to create a basic query with filters using [this guide from Apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/graphql/filtering/how-to-search-and-filter-results-with-graphql/). The error I receive in the sandbox response is:

> "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'liked')",
> "    at Object.movies (.../server/schema/resolvers.js:14:45)",

'liked' is a property in my dataset. I've tried changing the type definition and query to test other properties and the same error occurs.

```
// index.js
const { ApolloServer } = require("apollo-server");
const { typeDefs } = require("./schema/type-defs");
const { resolvers } = require("./schema/resolvers");

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`YOUR API IS RUNNING AT: ${url} :)`);
});
```

```
// FakeData.js
const MovieList = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Avengers Endgame",
    year: 2019,
    liked: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Interstellar",
    year: 2007,
    liked: true,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Superbad",
    year: 2007,
    liked: true,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Madagascar 12",
    year: 2073,
    liked: false,
  },
];

module.exports = { MovieList };
```

```
// type-defs.js
const { gql } = require("apollo-server");

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Movie {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    year: Int!
    liked: Boolean!
  }

  input MovieFilters {
    liked: Boolean!
    year: Int!
  }

  input MovieInput {
    filter: MovieFilters
  }

  type Query {
    movie(id: ID!): Movie
    movies(input: MovieInput): [Movie]!
  }
`;

module.exports = { typeDefs };
```

```
// resolvers.js
const { MovieList } = require("../FakeData");
const _ = require("lodash");

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    movies: (parent, args) => {
      const { filter } = args;
      const shouldApplyFilters = filter !== null;

      let movies = MovieList;

      if (!shouldApplyFilters) return movies;

      const shouldApplyLikedFilter = filter.liked !== null;
      const shouldApplyYearFilter = filter.year !== null;

      if (shouldApplyLikedFilter) {
        movies = movies
          .filter((a) => a.liked === filter.liked)
      }

      if (shouldApplyYearFilter) {
        movies = movies
          .filter((a) => a.year === filter.year)
      }

      return movies;
    },
  }
};

module.exports = { resolvers };
```

```
// query
query GetMoviesByFilter($input: MovieInput) {
  movies(input: $input) {
    id
    name
    liked
    year
  }
}
```

```
// variables
{
  "input": {
    "filter": {
      "year": 2007,
      "liked": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking your `filter` parameter against `null` when it is actually `undefined`. You can simplify your resolver as follows by taking advantage of javascript truthiness/falsyness:

```
movies: ( parent, { filter } ) => {
  let movies = MovieList;
  if (filter?.liked) movies = movies.filter((a) => a.liked === filter.liked)
  if (filter?.year) movies = movies.filter((a) => a.year === filter.year)
  return movies;
},
```

Comment: This resolved the undefined error and I appreciate the simplification of the code. I now receive the data from the MovieList but changing the filter variables doesn't effect the response. Did I miss something?

Comment: The filters should work! Would have to run through the debugger to see why they are not.

Comment: Did you get your filters working?